# Running a VBA code whenever you change the row you're editing

Tags: vba, excel

I need to run a code in excel VBA whenever you change the row you're working on.

My code updates other Workbooks whenever you edit something, but since all the information in a row is supposed to update 1 Workbook, I want it to open and update that other Workbook only when you stop working in a row (any row)

Right now I have a code that updates the other workbook when I change a cell, so this is what I have.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim dirFile As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim Actual As Workbook
    Static lngRow As Long
    Dim linea
    Set Actual = ActiveWorkbook
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
        dirFile = "N:\Otros\sebastian\TEST 2\"
        strFile = Trim(Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value)
        If Len(Dir(dirFile & strFile & ".xlsx")) = 0 Then
            Application.Visible = False

            linea = Target.Row
            Set WB = Workbooks.Add
            ' ESTILO
            ' __________________________
            WB.Worksheets(1).Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 28
            ' ___________________________
            'DATOS
            '____________________________

            WB.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Titulo de Proyecto"
            WB.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = Actual.Worksheets(1).Cells(linea, 2)
            WB.SaveAs (dirFile & strFile & ".xlsx")
            WB.Close
            Application.Visible = True


        End If



    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if you want to only trigger the updating of other workbooks after you leave a row you need to establish exactly what condition you want that to be. For example you could add a check before your message box to see if the currently selected cell is still on the same row and if it isn't then run the update. Is  something like that what you are wanting?

Comment: No, that message box is only a leftover from a code I took from elsewhere.

What I need is that, if you edit some cells from the same row, nothing happens, but when you select a cell in another row, I need it to open the other workbook and update some information there with the changes in the row.

I could leave it like that, but since each row represents a specific company project, all that opening and closing of Workbooks would be very annoying if someone just wants to update one project.

Comment: Then yes, you mean what I was saying. I was referring to the msg box location as the location for the check, either built into the existing if statement or as a nested if statement before any of the actual update code was run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global variable in the worksheet module to accomplish this.  The currRow variable is set to 0 when the sheet is activated (in case you switch to another sheet).  Then check the row of the target vs. the row previously on.

```
Private currRow As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    currRow = 0

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If currRow = Target.Row Then
       'Do Nothing
    Else
       If currRow <> 0 Then
                 'Do Rest of code then set the target to the new row
       End If
       currRow = Target.Row
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I got sidetracked at work and didn't get around to posting it myself.

Comment: @Bryan No problem.  Figured something like that as you obviously knew what you were doing.